# Manipulate or check what data is available in cache in firebase using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Is there any way to manipulate cache data available while offline mode in firebase using javascript ? or is there anyway to know that what data is available in cache on offline mode in firebase using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API to specifically manipulate the Firebase Database client's cache. But any write operation will automatically apply to the cached data (as well as to the server-side database when your connection is restored).

There is no public API to know what data is stored in the Firebase Database client's cache.